# Why does resolving forces in one direction give a completely different answer to resolving the opposite way?

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, intuition, classical-mechanics

[image: M4 q6]

I can solve parts i), ii) and am able to show that $R=0$ for part iii).
In this question $g$ is the acceleration of free fall taken to be $9.8$

Using Newtons 2nd law [$F=ma$] for the last part I resolved forces perpendicular to $PQ$ in the direction of $S$ to obtain $\displaystyle\ S- \frac{4mg}{5} = \frac{ma}{2}\alpha$  **(1)**

Where $\alpha=$ Tangential angular acceleration.

To obtain an expression for $\alpha$ I took moments about $X$ using Newtons 2nd law in angular form [$C=I\alpha$], where $C$ is applied couple or torque, and $I$ is the moment of inertia for the lamina.

This yielded:
$\displaystyle\frac{2mga}{5} = \frac{4ma^2\alpha}{3}$

Solving gives $\displaystyle\alpha=\frac{3g}{10a}$ (which the mark-scheme agrees with).

Substitution of $\displaystyle\alpha=\frac{3g}{10a}$ in **(1)** yields $\displaystyle\ S=\frac{19mg}{20}$ and according to the mark-scheme this is ***incorrect***.

The correct answer according to the mark-scheme is $\displaystyle\ S=\frac{13mg}{20}$
obtained from $\displaystyle\ \frac{4mg}{5} -S = \frac{ma}{2}\alpha$. This is what the mark-scheme says:
[image: mark-scheme]

So the real question is: **Why must $S$ and $\displaystyle\frac{ma}{2}\alpha$ be in opposite directions?**

Thank you kindly,

with best regards.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two forces acting on the lamina in the direction parallel to $S$ are $S$ itself
and $\dfrac45 mg,$ the component in that direction of the gravitational force on the
lamina. That component of gravitational force is opposite $S$.
So you are correct that the force in the direction of $S$ is
$$S - \frac45 mg.$$
Note that this is the force in an *upward* direction. (Not straight up, but still upward.)
If that force were positive, the center of mass of the lamina would be accelerated upward.

But the pivot is inert. The only force it exerts on the lamina is the equal and opposite
reaction necessary to keep the pivot point of the lamina from falling.
It can't stop the center of mass of the lamina from falling, which is why
the rotation of the lamina is accelerating at the point in time shown in the illustration.
The center of mass is accelerating in a downward direction at that time.

So the net force on the center of mass parallel to $S$ has to be downward, that is,
it must be opposite the direction of $S$, not the same direction.
In other words, the net force in the direction of $S$ is negative.
The force acting in the direction of positive $\alpha$ is the positive-valued force
that is opposite in direction to $S$, that is,
$$\frac45 mg - S.$$

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. It was my understanding that we were to resolve forces in the direction that would rotate the lamina with $\displaystyle\theta$ increasing which is the clockwise direction according to the diagrams, this is how i obtained $\displaystyle\ S- \frac{4mg}{5} = \frac{ma}{2}\alpha$. Are you saying that i'm to ignore the direction in which $\displaystyle\theta$ increases?

Comment: Since the lamina is rotating about the pivot point, and $S$ passes through the pivot point, $S$ (by itself) is acting neither clockwise nor counterclockwise.  The actual cause of the turning is gravity, which acts clockwise; $S$ is merely a reaction which stops the lamina from simply falling with acceleration $g$.

Answer (score 1):

i)$$I=m\frac{((2a)^2+(3a)^2)}{12}+m\left(\frac{3a}2-a\right)^2=\frac43ma^2$$
ii)$$\frac12I\omega_i^2+mga(1-\cos\theta)=\frac12I\omega_f^2\\
\implies w_f^2=\frac{6g}{5a}$$
iii)$$R=mg\cos\theta-m\omega_f^2\left(\frac{3a}2-a\right)=0$$
$$\alpha=\frac{\tau}I=\frac{mg\sin\theta\times\left(\frac{3a}2-a\right)}{\frac43ma^2}=\frac{3g}{10a}$$
$$mg\sin\theta-S=m\left(\frac{3a}2-a\right)\alpha\\
\implies S=\frac{13}{20}mg$$

---

**Explanation:**
[image]

Take directions with signs:

Towards $mg\sin\theta$ perpendicular to PQ positive and opposite negative, then using your same expression:
$$\displaystyle\ (-S)+\left(+\frac{4mg}{5}\right) = \left(+\frac{ma}{2}\alpha\right)$$
Actually this is a remainder of some vector form:
$$\vec S+\frac{4mg}{5}\hat d =\left(\frac{ma}2\right)\hat d$$
where $\hat d$ is in direction perpendicular to PQ along $mg\sin\theta$

Conclusively and easily $S$ and $\frac {ma}2\alpha$ are in opposite directions.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed answer, however i am still not satisfied that "Towards $mg\sin\theta$ perpendicular to PQ positive and opposite negative". Why must this be the case? Why cannot I have Towards $mg\sin\theta$ perpendicular to PQ **negative** and opposite **positive**?

Comment: then it would be $\displaystyle\ (+S)+\left(-\frac{4mg}{5}\right) = \left(-\frac{ma}{2}\alpha\right)$

Comment: Okay, now we're getting somewhere, I guess what i'm asking is why $S$ and $\displaystyle\frac {ma}2\alpha$ are in opposite directions? The reason I ask is $\theta$ increases clockwise so by my logic $S$ and $\displaystyle\frac {ma}2\alpha$ should be in the same direction. Unless you can tell me what is the direction of the tangential acceleration $\alpha$?

Comment: @144533 targeting acceleration would be in the direction of the ttorque which is applied by mg sin theta clockwise, imagine yourself pulling the lamina with string from the centre of the lamina towards right which is actually the clockwise direction

Comment: If i pulled the lamina with a string to the right from the center of mass i would be rotating the lamina in the counter-clockwise direction right? If this is the case for what purpose do we designate $\alpha$, $\omega$, $\theta$ clockwise?